# Confusing Debian PATH behaviour and `which` results with bash install script

Tags: bash, debian, path, node.js, raspbian

I installed Raspbian Jessie which comes with node v0.X which is the latest version of node that is available on Raspbian repositories. So I made a script which installs v6.7.0:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get remove nodejs node
if [ ! $(command -v node) ]; then
  mkdir -p ~/tmp
  pushd ~/tmp
  if [ ! -d node-v6.7.0-linux-armv6l ]; then
    if [ ! -f node-v6.7.0-linux-armv6l.tar.xz ]; then
      wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.7.0/node-v6.7.0-linux-armv6l.tar.xz
    fi
    tar -xJf node-v6.7.0-linux-armv6l.tar.xz
  fi
  cp -R node-v6.7.0-linux-armv6l/* /usr/local/
  popd
fi
```

But when I run `node -v` I get this:

> -bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory

And when I run `which node` I get no output. - And the script never executes the `if` branch, so node is not downloaded and nothing is put into `/usr/local`.

If I uninstalled nodejs using aptitude, why it it still looking in `/usr/bin/node`?

I have checked the `PATH` variable, it has both `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin`.

How can I modify the script to work as expected?

Comment: Did you run node in the same shell before uninstalling it?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a symlink /usr/bin/node pointing to some file that's missing. Check it with `ls -alp /usr/bin/node`. There can be a problem with /etc/alternatives etc.

You don't need to remove any package installed with apt to install a new version of Node.

If you want to install Node in a way that works, see my tutorial at:

- https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a

which incidentally explains how to correctly install Node 6.7.0 - just change the version to the one you need.

Instead of using that script that you have - that can fail for several reasons - for example when you have node-v6.7.0-linux-armv6l in /tmp, or if you already have node-v6.7.0-linux-armv6l.tar.xz in /tmp, or if you have a symlink in /usr/bin etc. do it manually like I describe in the tutorial for the binary packages. Just change the file name to the version that you need - e.g. node-v6.7.0-linux-armv6l.tar.gz if you want 6.7.0 for ARM.

Comment: Thanks - but I really need this scripted since it is used by a different and quite involved setup script that installs an OS and system from scratch. I've had it working on an OS that didn't come with node, but it doesn't work now that the OS does come with node. (I will address possible failure scenarios once I get basics working). I've tried running `ls -alp /usr/bin/node` as you suggested but it returns `ls: cannot access /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory`? I also ran `ls -l /etc/alternatives | grep node` and that also returns nothing?

Comment: @Jodes See the tutorial that I provided. It's a list of commands to run which is basically a script if you save it in a file. Additionally I explain what you need to take into account to run your programs with the newly installed Node versions - paths, environment variables, shebang lines etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that bash had run it previously, so has a hashed version in its cache.  You can read more about it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables).

You can confirm this by running

```
type node
```

and if you see something like

```
node is hashed (/usr/bin/node)
```

then this is indeed the problem.

You can clear all the hashes with `hash -r` or just this one with `hash -d node`

As an aside, `which` is really a tool that was written for `csh`, and there are edge cases where it doesn't work as expected in `bash`.  Consider using `type -p` and `command -v` to find locations with `bash` and get a really excellent write up on it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)